# Keeping libreoffice start command up to date

Tags: command-line, updates, libreoffice

Several pages provide the correct commands to start LO, such as:

```
libreoffice6.4 --writer
```

But whenever LO updates, that command must be changed. Is there a command which will catch up when LO updates?

Comment: [The official packages use `/usr/bin/libreoffice`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/all/libreoffice-common/filelist), not `/usr/bin/libreofficeX.Y`.

Comment: On your system, what is the output of `grep Exec= /usr/share/applications/libreoffice*.desktop`?

Comment: The output is a series of lines of the form: /usr/share/applications/libreoffice6.4-math.desktop:Exec=libreoffice6.4 --math %U

Comment: @muru, "libreoffice" on its own does not work on my system. Is it perhaps because I am using the fresh version or lo, not the stable version? If so, is there a way of telling the system to look for the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore those several pages. The correct command to start LibreOffice Writer is `lowriter`.

Comment: You may ignore them if you wish. lowriter does not work on my system, nor any variation of it I have tried. I have to specify the version number.

Comment: How did you install LibreOffice? It seems you are not using the regular Ubuntu package.

Comment: I downloaded the latest debs on libreoffice.org and installed them manually.

Comment: I see. Well in that case this is probably the wrong forum to ask since it is explicitly about the officially supported Ubuntu distribution. You'll have to ask in a LibreOffice forum how those packages are built and what mechanisms if any they propose in order to provide a stable command line.